# ReadTable in Matlab

Tags: matlab

When I use the `readtable` function I get the following error:

```
IVcellData = readtable('RiskModelData','Sheet',2,'Range','A1:A49')
```

> Error using readtable (line 129) Invalid parameter name: Sheet.

Would appreciate if anyone could help me.

Comment: Not: RiskModelData is the excel file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like you need to define extension:

```
T = readtable(filename) creates a table by reading column oriented data from a file.
    readtable determines the file format from the file name's extension:
    .txt, .dat, or .csv for delimited text files
    .xls, .xlsb, .xlsm, .xlsx, .xltm, .xltx, or .ods for spreadsheet files
```

try ReadModelData.xls or .xlsx

Comment: Thank you for the answer Mikhail.

Answer (score 1):

Have you renamed Sheet 2 to something else, e.g. Datafile? If so, you need to use this name (inside single quotes) not the sheet number instead of 2 in that call.

Also, you need to make a call to 
opts = detectImportOptions(yourfilename) 
before the call to readtable. I suspect this one is this cause as it is not recognising Sheet as a variable.

Took me a while to discover that lot, mostly empirical as the documentation is not clear on that point.
Keith